# tomcat https static content

Tags: tomcat, java, tomcat7

We are using tomcat to serve everything over http. BUT, we have a login page which is served over https since we have them enter a password. Recently, chrome has stopped supporting serving non secure content on secure pages. How do we configure Tomcat to serve static content over both http and https? Right now, the request comes in over https, and tomcat just redirects it to the http version.

Comment: Why not just serve everything over https? They would be much more simple, and should be what you're doing anyway.

Comment: That was my proposed solution as well, but my boss and team are reluctant to switch at the moment.